# MacBook Air Wi-Fi is not working -- how can I troubleshoot the problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, internet

I am trying to connect to Wi-Fi. It does get connected but there is no internet. I can't use Wi-Fi. Weird thing is that when I connect my iPad and iPhone to the same router/Wi-Fi they work perfectly fine. But my MacBook Air has some issue. How can I fix this problem?

My OS is 10.9.5.

Update

Wifi is working in safe mode.

Comment: Open the OS X  network settings > wifi > advanced and hit > Renew DHCP Lease button. Open safari and reload the webpage you are trying to open

Comment: Just tried it after your comment but still same issue. The thing is that it is keep getting the same ip after pressing renew dhcp lease.

Comment: Is it any wifi you can't connect or is it a specific network you can't connect?

Comment: Is this a one time issue, and does it persist after reboot?

Comment: #fsb I haven't tried with other wifi yet. For that I may go to Starbucks :(. # kisa this the first time it happened. I tried restarting my MacBook several times and also the router. The problem still exist.

Comment: Go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced... button - Select the problematical SSID in the list of Preferred Networks and click the minus (-) sign to delete it. Reconnect to the SSID with the proper credentials..

Comment: @icondaemon how can I know proper credentials of  Ssid and what do you mean by ssid? You mean network name?

Comment: SSID = network name. If this SSID has a username/password or just a password, those are credentials. Just delete this network name and re-connect to it.

Comment: I already tried these things before posting this question.

Comment: @ZafarSaleem - you said you tried these things before, please edit your question to show what you have attempted.  Also, it's helpful to provide your specific MBA model as components differ across the line.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that your network settings are corrupt.

**Reset your wifi settings**
Another option could be to reset the network and wifi settings.

a) In Macintosh HD/ Library / Preferences / SystemConfiguration

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
```

- Move those files to the trash
- Reboot your Mac
- Reconnect to your wifi

b) Alternatively you can open SystemPreferences > Networks > select Wifi and delete it. In the second step re-add the wifi service again.

**Upgrade to macOS**
If possible try updating your Mac to the latest macOS version. Open the AppStore and download Mac Sierra.

**Disable Third-Party Software**
Do you use any kind of Firewall Apps e.g. Little Snitch. If so, temporarily disable them.

Comment: I couldn't find these files in that location at all. I will update once I have wifi :)

Comment: It was called differently in OS X Mavericks. Do you see a file called com.apple.airport.preferences.plist? If so. Delete it and reboot your Mac.

Comment: In safe mode wifi is working. See my update in question.

Comment: I didn't find that file either

Comment: Another option: Connect your MacBook with your router using a Ethernet cable. Than update to OS X 10.12

Comment: It is MacBook Air no Ethernet slot

Comment: Yes, there's also a Thunderbold Ethernet adapter available

Comment: To help you further. What files are available in Macintosh HD/ Library / Preferences / SystemConfiguration?

Comment: There are bunch of files but the one that is related wifi is com.apple.wifi.keychain-format.plist which I already moved to trash

Comment: Open SystemPreferences > Networks > select Wifi and delete it. In the second step read the wifi service again. Moreover do you use any kind of Firewall Apps e.g. Little Snitch. If so, temporarily disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting your computer's System Management Controller (SMC)?

**For the MacBook Air, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Also, another thing worth doing is resetting your NVRAM.

**To reset your NVRAM do this:**

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**[EDIT]**

Since we've established it works in Safe Mode, this means we've eliminated both the possibility of a network/router issue or a hardware issue. This is good, because it must be related to some sort of 'software' or 'data' issue. There is a remote possibility it will now work when started up normally, as booting in Safe Mode will have cleared some data.

If it doesn't, as another test, try creating another User Account and testing that. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Click on Users & Groups
3. Click on the + sign at bottom left (you may need to unlock the padlock before you can make changes)
4. In your Login Options turn off Automatic Login and also ensure you display your login window as a list of users
5. Exit System Preferences
6. Shutdown your computer
7. Reboot your computer and then login by selecting the User you just created
8. Try connecting to WiFi

Please report back on the outcome.

Comment: Which is control button?

Comment: It may be Ctrl on your keyboard.

Comment: Tried both but still e same issue :(

Comment: Have you got an iPhone or other device from which you can share a personal hotspot from? If so it'd be good to do that and see if you can connect to that from the MacBook Air. Basically we need to identify if this is a problem specific to your WiFi network/router setup or not.

Comment: I just went to Starbucks and I had the same issue there.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  I would try the first part of the answer from @howdytom . That is, everything but upgrading to Sierra. Another thing to try is booting into Safe Mode and seeing if that makes any difference. Do this by holding the SHIFT key down during startup and trying to connect to WiFi again.

Comment: IN safe mode wifi is working

Comment: any help after finding out that wifi is fine

Comment: This is great. I've updated my answer with another test to try.

Comment: Nope after safe mode I restarted and wifi still didn't work. Created new user and shutdown and turn on still didn't work.

Comment: any further help in this issue?

Comment: Something you've installed or configured is affecting your internet connection. Some sort of 3rd party software, driver, etc is causing the problem. That's why it works fine in Safe Mode, because Safe Mode doesn't load these. Is there anything you've recently changed? Installed any new software? Bought any new hardware (printers etc)? If nothing has changed, then doing a clean install of macOS may be warranted. If so, you may or may not want to upgrade to a newer OS, but there's nothing inherently wrong with staying on OS X 10.9.5 although it's no longer technically supported since September.